# ASP.NET - UpdatePanel - RegisterClientScriptInclude - Async Postback - ScriptLoadFailedException

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel

When using a update panel and register a script with RegisterClientScriptInclude, the browser gives the following error.

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException: 
The script '...' failed to load.

Answer (score 0):

I did found the following solutions on the internet, you need to combine those two.

**Part A** - https://siderite.dev/blog/including-external-javascript-on-async.html -
Add the following jscript to the end of the file you are including.

```
if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

**Part B** - http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/10/20/Gotcha-WebKit-(Safari-3-and-Google-Chrome)-Bug-with-ASPNET-AJAX.aspx - Add a script to youre sync postback so its available before the async part comes.

```
Sys.Browser.WebKit = {}; //Safari 3 is considered WebKit
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('WebKit/') > -1)
{
    Sys.Browser.agent = Sys.Browser.WebKit;
    Sys.Browser.version = parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.match(/WebKit\/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/)[1]);
    Sys.Browser.name = 'WebKit';
 }
```